# Problems Signing a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to sign a simple script to show my students.  When I sign the script, which I created in Notepad, I get an unknown error using Set-AuthicodeSignature. When I look at the script after trying to sign in Notepad is shows a signature block.  When I try to run it says the PowerShell says the script is not signed.  I am using an executionpolicy of AllSigned. Any suggestions?  The script runs fine if I set the executionpolicy of Unrestricted.

Comment: unknown error? is that the actual error text? you might find luck posting the exception anyways.

Comment: @colsw Yes, this **IS** an actual error text

Answer (score 3):

For the error in Set-AuthenticodeSignature, Chances are your character encoding is not in UTF-8.  You can change the character encoding to UTF-8 within notepad and things will work just fine.  This is the most common cause of the "unknown error"

Regarding the next issue, of getting the script to run.  From `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies` the AllSigned policy:

```
 - Scripts can run.

 - Requires that all scripts and configuration files
   be signed by a trusted publisher, including scripts
   that you write on the local computer.
```

We have a couple of options here.  We could trust the certificate that we created at a higher level (by adding it to a trusted store), we can use a different certificate from a root CA, also trusted at a higher level and lastly, we could use a different ExecutionPolicy.  Also from `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies` you may want to try using "RemoteSigned" as that will allow you to run self-signed scripts you wrote on your own machine, as well as trusted scripts downloaded from the internet:

```
  RemoteSigned
      - Scripts can run. This is the default execution
        policy in Windows Server 2012 R2.

      - Requires a digital signature from a trusted
        publisher on scripts and configuration files that
        are downloaded from the Internet (including
        e-mail and instant messaging programs).

    - Does not require digital signatures on scripts that
        you have written on the local computer (not
        downloaded from the Internet).

      - Runs scripts that are downloaded from the Internet
        and not signed, if the scripts are unblocked, such
        as by using the Unblock-File cmdlet.

      - Risks running unsigned scripts from sources other
        than the Internet and signed, but malicious, scripts.
```

Comment: You are right.  I had not added the certificate to a trusted store. I seem to remember this had happened earlier and the error was different.  That is what had me confused.